# Replace folder in file system using Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2, filesystems, nsfilemanager

How can I copy and paste the entire content of a folder using Swift on a OS X? If the destinationPath already contains the folder, than it should replace it.

I tried

```
let appSupportSourceURL = NSURL(string: appSupportSourcePath)
        let appSupportDestinationURL = NSURL(string: appSupportDestinationPath+"/"+appSupportFileName)

        if (fileManager.isReadableFileAtPath(appSupportSourcePath)){
            do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(appSupportSourceURL!, toURL: appSupportDestinationURL!)}
            catch{   
            }
        }
```

but I realised, that this only works for files. I am trying to replace a whole folder.

Answer (score 1):

I know Apple encourages new code to use the URLs to specify file system path. However `NSFileManager` is an old class and it's still in transition between the old string-based path and the new URL-based paradigm. Try this:

```
let appSupportSourcePath = "..."
let appSupportDestinationPath = "..."

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
do {
    // Delete if already exists
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(appSupportDestinationPath) {
        try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(appSupportDestinationPath)
    }
    try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(appSupportSourcePath, toPath: appSupportDestinationPath)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

**Edit:** method with `NSURL`

```
let appSupportSourceURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "...", isDirectory: true)
let appSupportDestionURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "...", isDirectory: true)

try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(appSupportSourceURL, toURL: appSupportDestionURL)
```